# SQL Creating New Table that is based of a column in an already created table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is an example of what I need, different values:
I already have table 1 created in the database.
Table 1: Person
Columns: PK->ID, Name, Favorite Color, Favorite Sport, etc..
This table is already in database and filled with values.

Now I want to create a second table, Table 2 which has a primary key of Favorite Sport column from my Table 1 and just one more column for the description.
Ex:
Table 2: Sports
Columns: Pk->Favorite Sport, description

I want to make sure I am just creating this table correctly, so I don't mess anything up. Would this be the correct syntax to use? (I will fill up the data separately after table is created.)

CREATE TABLE Sports (
Favorite_Sport Varcher(25),
Description Varcher(100),
PRIMARY KEY(Favorite_Sport),
Foreign KEY(Favorite_Sport) REFERENCES Person;
)

Thanks!

Comment: not even close, you need to read the SQL manual, start here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_4.htm). I'm assuming your are using 11g

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do this, but I think I'd go with

```
CREATE TABLE Sports
  (SPORT        Varchar2(25)
     CONSTRAINT PK_SPORTS
       PRIMARY KEY
       USING INDEX,
   Description  Varchar2(100));
```

(I changed the name of the primary key column on the SPORTS table to SPORT).

You really don't want nor can you have SPORTS.SPORT reference PERSON.FAVORITE_SPORT, as FAVORITE_SPORT is not a primary or unique key on PERSON. Instead, you want the foreign key relationship to go the other way around, with PERSON.FAVORITE_SPORT referencing SPORTS.SPORT:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON
  ADD CONSTRAINT PERSON_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (FAVORITE_SPORT) REFERENCES SPORTS(SPORT);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab1fc)

Best of luck.